# Write json object with controller using rendered jsp

Tags: json, jsp, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC.
I want to render some jsp by forwarding to it. And then I want to write the result to json.

For exmple I want to render my complex jsp and on exit I want to get:
{"result":"ok","html":"......."}

How can I do this?
I've tried to look at
request.getRequestDispatcher("tutorMini").forward(request, response)
But if I can't pass response to it, bcz it should write all output to it.

And I've tried to use some json tags in jsp, but it has some troubles with hierarchy:
[HTML output with jsp:include and json-taglib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476508/html-output-with-jspinclude-and-json-taglib)

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to apply additional conversion when inserting HTML into JSON (escape `'` and `"`), you cannot write output of your JSP to the response directly.

So, you need to create an instance of [`ServletResponseWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponseWrapper.html) that would save the output (by overriding `getWriter()` and/or `getOutputStream()`) and pass it to `RequestDispatcher.include()` (it looks more appropriate than `forward()` for this case):

```
MyServletResponseWrapper wrapper = new MyServletResponseWrapper(response);
request.getRequestDispatcher("tutorMini").include(request, wrapper);
String html = wrapper.getSavedOutput();
```

Then you can insert the saved content into JSON, escaping it appropriately.

Comment: And what should I write in MyServletResponseWrapper? Is there any fake implementation of it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701681/how-can-i-read-an-httpservletreponses-output-stream